# How to chage the properties for controls inside a template field?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a templatefield having a textbox and filteredtextboxextender inside the templatefield. I need to change the ValidChars property for filteredtextboxextender from "123" to "abc" in c# codebehind. The templatefield is there inside the GridView.
I used the following code in aspx page.

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdEducation" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                        AllowPaging="false" CellPadding="4" GridLines="Vertical" OnRowDeleting="grdEducation_RowDeleting"
                        OnRowDataBound="grdEducation_RowDataBound" OnRowUpdating="grdEducation_RowUpdating" ShowFooter="false" ShowHeader="true">
                        <HeaderStyle CssClass="grid-header-style" />
                        <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-CssClass="grid-label-small" >`   

    <ItemTemplate>
                                    <table>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td width='90%'>
                                                <table>
                                                <td width='60%'>
                                                        <asp:TextBox ID="textbox1" Width="100px" runat="server"
                                                            ToolTip="Provide text" MaxLength="11"></asp:TextBox>
                                                        <ajaxtoolkit:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="filter" runat="server" TargetControlID="textbox1"
                                                            ValidChars="123" />

                                                    </td>
                                                </table>
    </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Is there any possibility is there for change filteredtextboxextender property like that like that?

Thank you..

Comment: Which data bound control is being used?

Comment: Please show the code for your.. gridview? and template fields and the textboxes you are trying to modify. Also show code for anything you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Register the `RowBoundData` event like below.

```
protected void GridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        YourControlType Conrol = (YourControlType)e.Row.FindControl("ControlID");
        //Set the property here
    }
}
```

You can similarly change the Control Properties in `Row_Command` event also

Comment: @Kathirvel - You removed the `GridView` `Mark up` from your Query ?